# How to know if block content is empty in Jade

Tags: node.js, express, pug

How can we check if block is exist in Jade, I'm trying to make a template in Jade where in i have following block in layout.jade and in login.jade i have extended layout.jade. Now when in account.jade i will have both left and main content blocks

```
extend layout.jade
   div(class='col-md-4')
      block leftcontainer
   div(class='col-md-8')
      block content
```

Now in login.jade i want to hide

```
   div(class='col-md-4')
       block leftcontainer
```

and make the main content full page, if leftcontainer is not there. It should look like this

```
  div(class='col-md-12')
     block content
```

if user is on some page i want to hide left column block. Say if user is in login page then

Answer (score 1):

If I got it right, you wan't to hide a block if a user (e.g. a user who is logged in to your app) is at a certain page. If this is right do something like this:

Example with [Express](http://expressjs.com/) & [Passport](http://passportjs.org/):

```
// server
app.get('/login', function(req, res){
  if(req.isAuthenticated()) {
    res.render('login', { 'user' : req.user } );
  } else {
    res.render('login', { 'user' : null } );
  }
});

// layout
extend layout.jade
  if user !== null
    div(class='col-md-12')
      block content
  else
    div(class='col-md-4')
       block leftcontainer
    div(class='col-md-8')
       block content
```

In general you can work with other conditional statements in Jade, without Passport, this was just an example. You may want to take a look at the [reference](http://jade-lang.com/reference/), especially under conditional or case.